# Why do I get Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

```
boolean r = ofy().transact(new Work<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean run() {
            Visit visit = ofy().load().type(Visit.class)
                    .filter(Visit.USER_ID, userID)
                    .filter(Visit.VENUE_ID, venueID).first().get();

            if (visit == null)
                return false;

            visit.setLastRequestDate(new Date(timestamp));

            ofy().save().entity(visit).now();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions.

for the line with the `get()` call.
why? I'm only querying `Visit` entity in this transaction.
I'm doing this in a transaction, because I want all this to be performed as atom operation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No way to do ancestor-less query inside a transaction. Either you do it without transactions or replace query with get.

The closest that you can do is:

1. Get entity with ancestor-less query without transaction. Remember key of the entity.
2. Start transaction.
3. Get entity via the key.
4. Check that query condition still applies (= properties still have the same values as in query conditions). This way you can be sure entity was not changed since you did the query.
5. Change & save entity. Commit transaction.

Comment: thank you it's a great work around, it will also help me in another queries.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation that made sense! I had wondered ... docs say you can access root entities in xg-transactions but when I tried, I ran into this

Comment: I am pretty new w/ Objectify...can someone clear up the part "...replace query with get...?"  Have no idea what that means.  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyWu what he means is that you replace the query with a get by key. So you're now retrieving the object by its key and not querying for it by any of its field values.

Answer (score -6):

The error seems quite clear: inside a transaction, you're only allowed to perform ancestor queries. Your query is not an ancestor query.

Comment: can you please elaborate more? ancestor query are queries from the same entity group, aren't they? and in my query I have only one entity

Comment: @RCB - no, it's not a query that returns one entity. Ancestor queries are queries where you define ancestor as part of query conditions.

Comment: @PeterKnego - OK, but `Visit` doesn't have any ancestor (root). So, how should I do this? Can you, maybe, provide me with an example.

Comment: @PeterKnego - Regardless, thank you very much. I've noticed that you've been answering many of my questions. So, once again thank you

Comment: @RCB: I created my own answer with approximate solution.

Comment: This is captain obvious answer.