# Check unique player with objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, nosql

I use objectify with GAE and I want to create unique player by pseudo. I know that there is no unique key like sql database. So I tried to use transaction to do it. I want to start my transaction, search if there is already a player with this pseudo, and create the player if not.

```
Player player = ofy().load().type(Player.class).filter("pseudo =", tmpPseudo).first().now();
```

But this doesn't work because there is a filter. Now I'm stuck because I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to mark the field *pseudo* with the @Index annotation like this:

Player.java

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;

@Index
String pseudo;
```

so it can be filtered by that field.

Comment: I already did this. The error is
    Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions.

Comment: what do you mean with "this doesn't work"? an exception or no player loaded? Edit- ok sorry, I guess now that "Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions" is the message of the exception

Comment: have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397207/why-do-i-get-only-ancestor-queries-are-allowed-inside-transactions-error

Comment: Yes I checked this one. But the matter is that I have to check if there is not already a player with a given pseudo. So if I try to get a player with this pseudo and get nothing I get into the transaction. But during this time, an other player can do the same and enter in the transaction too. And both will be added a player with the same pseudo.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest strategy is to check if it is used, write, then requery after the save.  If you get two results and yours is the older one, delete the row and return an error (or whatever).  There is still the possibly of missing it though due to "eventual consistency" constraints in datastore.  Adding a delay before the requery can help but depending on app load may not really be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved my problem by copying the object into the transaction.

`final Player player = ofy().load().type(Player.class).filter("pseudo =", tmpPseudo).first().now();`

Then inside transaction I do the check instead of before the transaction:

`Player currentPlayer = player`

if the `currentPlayer == null` ==> create player, otherwise no.