# GCP Datastore com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: queries inside transactions must have ancestors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

A simple find entity(Simple entity, no descendants relationship) make changes and save the entity in the same transaction.

But result in below error.

```
21:46:47.883 [Test worker] ERROR c.f.r.e.CustomExceptionControllerAdvice - Application exception occurred
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: queries inside transactions must have ancestors
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:128)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:181)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:177)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:176)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:170)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.TransactionImpl.run(TransactionImpl.java:96)
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.DatastoreTemplate.queryKeysOrEntities(DatastoreTemplate.java:266)
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.repository.query.GqlDatastoreQuery.execute(GqlDatastoreQuery.java:145)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.findByHash(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

After quite test and comparing 2 gcp projects, noticed that, the same code runs without any error(above exception) when application connected to gcp project which is having Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode database instance.

When application connected to a gcp project which is Firestore in Native mode database instance, resulting in above error.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore

Answer (score 0):

Datastore transactions operate only on entities coming from the same [entity group](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities#Transactions_and_entity_groups), descended from a common ancestor. In order to keep this restriction, all queries in a transaction must include an ancestor filter that specifies an ancestor in the same entity group as the other operations in the transaction.

From the official [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/cloud-datastore-transactions#transactions_and_entity_groups) on Firestore in Datastore mode:

> If you want to use queries within a transaction, your data must be
> organized into entity groups in such a way that you can specify
> **ancestor** filters that will match the right data.

Have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397207#answer-14400521) post on StackOverflow that is describing a possible workaround.